# How to make Scrollable homepage in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
body: Column( // want to make it scrollable
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black,),
            hintText: 'Search product .....',
          
        ),
      ),
    ),

    CarouselSlider(
      options: CarouselOptions(
        autoPlay: true,
        aspectRatio: 2.0,
        enlargeCenterPage: true,
      ),
      items: [
        Image.asset('images/drumstick.png'),
        Image.asset('images/pizza.png'),
      ],
    ),
```

How to make the body to Scrollable widget with the add of carousel slider? Because it will be error when i add scrollable widget. Please help me. Thank you in advance :) I am the beginner in flutter

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your Column with `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
```

```dart
 return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  suffixIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  hintText: 'Search product .....',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                autoPlay: true,
                aspectRatio: 2.0,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
              ),
              items: [
                Image.asset('images/drumstick.png'),
                Image.asset('images/pizza.png'),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox( // dummy widget to test
              height: 1222,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Also check more about [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) and [widgets/scrolling](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/scrolling)

Comment: but i want Scrollable widget because want to show the scroll bar on the right side homepage?

Comment: I think it should provide scrollbar by default, btw I am referring to the body scrollbar

Comment: i got the solution for the first problem, but when i want to scroll to the top , the homepage can't scroll. Only able scroll to bottom. Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting what exactly you are referring to. You may want CustomScrolView on your case, Also try `primary:false` on scrollable widget if it has in your case.

Comment: body: CustomScrollView(
        primary: false,
        children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
              child: TextField(

Comment: i got error on 'children: [ ' part

Comment: For `CustomScrollView` you need to use `slivers` instead of `children` and inner widget must have to be sliver type. Try [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) For now try with SingleChildScrollView and set primary false to inner scollable widget.

Comment: how to add the sliver at the inner widget? I got this error: Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

Comment: try checking https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html